# Rails: Take an unformatted datetime and assign it a time zone w/o changing the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I'm importing an object from an API with a datetime that looks like this:

`"2017-06-28 09:00:00"`

This time is in the user's time zone, which is known in my application. (i.e. `Pacific Time (US & Canada)`)

Datetimes are stored in my database as `datetime` format in UTC. When we display dates on the front-end, we account for the user's time zone (ie `datetime.in_time_zone(user_time_zone)`).

How do I save the datetime in my database correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to append your apps timezone to the end of the datetime string.

```
time = "2017-06-28 09:00:00"
time += Time.zone.name
```

Parsing that will give you the time in `Pacific Time (US & Canada)`. Or use `ActiveSupport`.

```
time_pacific = DateTime.parse(time)

### ActiveSupport version ###

time_pacific = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(Time.zone.name).parse("2017-06-28 09:00:00")
```

You can then call `#utc` on that to get the correct UTC time from your original string.

```
time_utc = time_pacific.utc
```